# AngularJS Iterate over ajax returned object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I am writing a program to learn AngularJS. This program has an ajax function that returns an object from an API endpoint, like so:

```
$.ajax(
  {
    url: "/api/request.json",
    dataType: "json",
    statusCode: {
      404: function(){
        console.log("Error 404");
      }
    },
    success: function(data){
      console.log("Successfully copied data to meteo_values");
      fn(data); // do something with the data
    },
    error: function(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
);
```

I would like to iterate through the object that is returned using AngularJS. Right now I'm using jQuery to inject the data inside a div, like so:

```
function fn(val){
  // populate the webpage with the values

  var data_table = "<div class='data_table'><p>" + datetext + "</p>";
  // iterate through val array
  for (var value in val){

    data_table += "<div class='card'><h2>" + val[value]["city"] + "</h2>";
    data_table += "<table><tr><th>Orario</th><th>Temperatura</th><th>Umidità</th></tr>";
    data_table += "<tr><td>" + val[value]["t1"]["ora"] + "</td><td>" + val[value]["t1"]["temperatura"] + "</td><td>" + val[value]["t1"]["humidity"] + "</td></tr>";
    data_table += "<tr><td>" + val[value]["t2"]["ora"] + "</td><td>" + val[value]["t2"]["temperatura"] + "</td><td>" + val[value]["t2"]["humidity"] + "</td></tr>";
    data_table += "<tr><td>" + val[value]["t3"]["ora"] + "</td><td>" + val[value]["t3"]["temperatura"] + "</td><td>" + val[value]["t3"]["humidity"] + "</td></tr>";
    data_table += "</table></div>";
  }
  data_table += "</div>"
  $(".results").append(data_table);
}
```

Instead of doing that (which works, but it doesn't seem elegant), I would like to use AngularJS. I tried using ng-repeat but It didn't work out.
Consider that the returned object is an object that contains an array of n objects which also contain another set of three objects.

I already tried `ng-repeat="(key,value) for name_of_the_variable_in_the_$scope"`

I might have forgot useful info for you to help me and answer and I already searched for the answer but I didn't find it.

EDIT:

```
var meteoApp = angular.module('meteoapp', []);

meteoApp.controller('meteoPopulateCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.data = [];

  $.ajax(
    {
      url: "/api/request.json",
      dataType: "json",
      statusCode: {
        404: function(){
          console.log("Error 404");
        }
      },
      success: function(data){
        $scope.data = data;
      },
      error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  );
```

HTML MARKUP

```
<div ng-app="meteoapp">
  <div ng-controller="meteoPopulateCtrl">
    <div class="results" ng-repeat="???">
      something that is repeated
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

RETURNED OBJECT (To be prettified)

```
[
  {
    "city":"a city",
    "t1":
    {
      "ora":"01",
    "temperatura":"7.2°",
    "humidity":"92%"},
    "t2":
    {
      "ora":"04",
      "temperatura":"7.1°",
      "humidity":"93%"},
    "t3":
    {
      "ora":"07",
      "temperatura":"7.4°",
      "humidity":"94%"
    }
}]
```

Comment: Can you post angular controller and html code that you used to test?

Comment: This seems to be a **very basic use of [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)**.

Comment: ^^^^  + Use `$http()` instead of `$.ajax()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is in angularjs, you should use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for displaying it on html page.

Here is the basic example of ng-repeat:

HTML:

```
<h3>FIFA Mactch Summary:</h3>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(country,goals) in items">{{country}}: {{goals}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var m = {
    "India": "2",
    "England": "2",
    "Brazil": "3",
    "UK": "1",
    "USA": "3",
    "Syria": "2"
};

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = m;
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/austinnoronha/4vGUL/)

For **ajax request** you should be using `$http` because `$http callbacks are all wrapped in $scope.$apply()`. Else you need to call **$scope.$apply()** which will call **$scope.$digest()** for you.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` will do the job - you need to remember to refresh the scope before asynchronously loaded content will be displayed. Try `$scope.$apply()` after receiving the response and the `ng-repeat` should pick it up.

Hope this helps.